# How to get files off a 23 year old Polaroid PDC-3000

Tags: digital, polaroid

I off loaded some .PDN files off an old digital camera, but can't seem to find any apps that read them. This is not to be confused with Paint.NET PDN files. This is polaroid old digital file type.

I think it stands for polaroid digital negative, but again it's over 20 years old now.

Comment: Can you post a link to one of the *.PDN* files?

Comment: FWIW I just saw a Polaroid PDC-700 for $25 on amazon that looks like it comes with the requisite software.  Not sure if it is compatible though

Comment: And I just read a PDC-700 manual that suggests that you can import photos from a PDC-300.  This is all just speculation for me so I'm not going to make an answer out of it

Comment: A link to a pdn file would allow others to check whether answers actually work.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like someone did actually care for this piece of software. 
The driver for your camera can be found here: 
http://www.opendrivers.com/download/driver-25829.html
It allows to convert the PDN files into tiff files.

Comment: Nice find, note that the original downloadlink is down, but the [back-up](http://dl2.opendrivers.com/dl_file.php?dl=dl2&brand=cameras-and-mp3-player%2Fpolaroid&file=pdc3000_package.exe&check=f6fk087tb6d04c&driver=378d9p) on the lower part of the page works.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else came across this searching like I did:

The PDC-3000 camera does not behave with the easy to find and very available PDC-2000 direct or Twain drivers for the PDC-2000 model (that I know work otherwise because I have a PDC-2000 as well). I tried for quite a while to see if it was anything with the SCSI drivers, software config, etc. with no success.

The driver linked earlier is no longer up, neither of the download links work.

Since this topic was posted in 2020, it appears that someone uploaded the "PDC Studio" software on internet archive.
https://archive.org/details/polariod-pdc-studio-software-3.5-cd-rom

I just installed it on my Windows 98 machine and it allows you to convert images from any folder on your machine. Tested and working, I just pulled some off the PDC-3000 I received yesterday! You need to go into PDC studio and select "folder" from image source in the preferences tab and select whatever folder on your PC that you're dumping the .pdn files into.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you find a meticulous old-software archivist who also cared/cares about early digital cameras, you're probably out of luck. From a 10-year-old comment to a photo of a [PDC-3000 at Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jonjon_01/2472213441):

> Also the old PDC software is near impossible to find. If anyone needs it for free I posted it on my blog: www.ebayisfun.com - Also note the the pdc_3000 software is 16 bit software so if you are running XP you need to run it in Win 95 compatibility mode.

(The website is dead. According to WHOIS the domain is available for purchase)

Even if you find a copy of the sofware (unlikely), you will need to run it in Windows XP (I would recommend using an XP virtual machine).

This is exactly why the free (as in liberty) software community advocates against proprietary data formats: if the software that parses the proprietary format is not free and is discontinued, the data in those files is usually unrecoverable.

Comment: I tried tracking the file through the Internet Archive but it does not appear to be there either.  Also had a look at the dcraw sources and it does not seem to support Polaroid Digital Negatives.  Had a quick look at Sourceforge and Github but can't see anything that does the conversion.

Comment: @StephenG Yeah, I tried digging around different warez sites, program archives, etc. This program suffers from being highly niche (that is, how many PDC-3000s were sold?), very old, and long unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

I found a review of the camera at:

[Imaging Resource](https://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/P3K/P3KA.HTM)

Towards the end of the review, the text in RED mentions:

> The PDC-3000 outputs very large files in an uncompressed TIFF format.

Not sure if this will be of any help, but worth a try.

Comment: It's entirely possible that they create a TIFF file, but use a proprietary `.PDN` extension to make people buy their software. It would be worth a try to rename an image from `*.PDN` to `*.TIF` to see if modern image processing software will recognize it.

Comment: PDN stands for Polaroid Digital Negative and seems to be a kind of RAW file - not a TIFF.  From what little I read there's some kind of compression involved as well, although it could be as simple as dropping bits that are below threshold.